# How to Select Data Between Two Dates and Times in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, datetime

[image: Mysql Query]why this query gives me the wrong output although I am trying to print data between '01-May-2022' and '30-May-2022';

why is this query giving me apr data?

Comment: Because those are strings not dates. MySQL date format is yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are storing your dates as *text*.  You should not be doing this, and the best long term fix is to make `datee` a proper date column.  As a short term fix, you may use `STR_TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT datee
FROM customer_shopping_details_tbl
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datee, '%d-%b-%Y') BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-05-30';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, 
Is it mandatory to have to follow this format (  '2022-05-01' AND '2022-05-30';) because I have savaed__String__ in the format of  01-May-2022   and 30-May-2022 like this...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all ....
I did a mistake while saving the date, I had saved the date in the string format. That is the reason that the query does not show proper output
What I learned/point to remember
-MySQL date format is yyyy-mm-dd
-Save your date in the form of date NOT IN String

go through the comments for the better idea

I have saved my data in the form of String so i have fired the following query and is working now

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Good evening,

Maybe this could help:

```
SELECT login,datetime FROM log where datetime between
to_date(’01-jan-2004,’mm/dd/yyyy’) and
to_date(’21-jan-2004′,’mm/dd/yyy’)
order by datetime DESC;
```

Comment: This is Oracle code but the OP is using MySQL.

Comment: Sir  @Tim Biegeleisen is right that 'I am storing date in the string format that is the reason it wont work '